# SQL Server stored procedure store 2 table variable in 1 table with from and to values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this table stored in variable `@oldValues` and `@newValues`:

[image]

The two tables above will contain 1 row maximum. My goal is to insert this to a new table JSON TABLE:

```
DECLARE @jsonTable TABLE
                   (
                       [Field] nvarchar(max),
                       [From] nvarchar(max),
                       [To] nvarchar(max)
                   );
```

and store the from to values from old and new variable

Output must be like this:

```
[Field]             [From]  [To]      // this is a column name
------------------------------------
CommitteeID         1       1
CommitteeName       Test    Test2
CommitteeMemberID   1       3
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can `@oldValues` and `@newValues`  have more rows?

Comment: no it will only contain 1 row maximum

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one row:

```
select v.*
from @oldValues ov cross join
     @newValues nv outer apply
     (values ('CommitteeId', ov.CommitteeId, nv.CommitteeId),
             ('CommitteeName', ov.CommitteeName, nv.CommitteeName),
             ('CommitteeMemberID', ov.CommitteeMemberID, nv.CommitteeMemberID)
     ) v(field, [from], [to]);
```

Note:  This assumes that the types for the values are all compatible.  Otherwise, you may need to convert/cast values to strings.

EDIT:

To be explicit, the casts are:

```
select v.*
from @oldValues ov cross join
     @newValues nv outer apply
     (values ('CommitteeId', cast(ov.CommitteeId as nvarchar(255)), cast(nv.CommitteeId as nvarchar(255))),
             ('CommitteeName', cast(ov.CommitteeName as nvarchar(255)), cast(nv.CommitteeName as nvarchar(255))),
             ('CommitteeMemberID', cast(ov.CommitteeMemberID as nvarchar(255)), cast(nv.CommitteeMemberID as nvarchar(255)))
     ) v(field, [from], [to]);
```

Comment: i got this error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test' to data type int." you can try edit it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83914/column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-definition-error

Comment: oh, i finally got it base on the answer by Serg, i just add cast the id to varchar. well thank you very much

Comment: @SecretCoder . . . I explained in the original answer that you might need to do a conversion.  I just added the explicit code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be plain

```
select 'CommitteeId' [Field], (select cast(CommitteeId as varchar(max)) from @oldValues) [From], (select cast(CommitteeId as varchar(max)) from @newValues)[To]
union all 
select 'CommitteeName', (select CommitteeName from @oldValues), (select CommitteeName from @newValues)
union all
select 'CommitteeId', (select cast(CommitteeMemberId as varchar(max)) from @oldValues), (select cast(CommitteeMemberId as varchar(max)) from @newValues)
```

Comment: this is working but what if there are 50 column fields. you will also make 50 union all??

Comment: Exactly. But first I'd thing about where those 2 tables come from.

Comment: well thanks, if theres no suggestion by tommorow then i will use this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think **UNPIVOT** operator most proper solution for the need.

For UNPIVOT operation all column types should be same, that's why we cast all column type to the same.

```
DECLARE @oldValues as TABLE (CommitteeID INT, CommitteeName VARCHAR(20), CommitteeMemberID INT)
INSERT INTO @oldValues VALUES (1,'Test',1)

DECLARE @newValues as TABLE (CommitteeID INT, CommitteeName VARCHAR(20), CommitteeMemberID INT)
INSERT INTO @newValues VALUES (1,'Test2',3)

DECLARE @jsonTable TABLE
(
    [Field] nvarchar(max),
    [From] nvarchar(max),
    [To] nvarchar(max)
);

;WITH FromTable AS (
    SELECT [Field] , [From] 
    FROM (SELECT CAST(CommitteeID AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeID, 
            CAST(CommitteeName AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeName, 
            CAST(CommitteeMemberID AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeMemberID  
            FROM @oldValues) p  
    UNPIVOT ( [From] FOR [Field] 
                IN ( CommitteeID , CommitteeName , CommitteeMemberID)) as UNPVT
)
, ToTable AS (
    SELECT [Field] , [To] 
    FROM (SELECT CAST(CommitteeID AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeID, 
            CAST(CommitteeName AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeName, 
            CAST(CommitteeMemberID AS VARCHAR(255)) CommitteeMemberID 
            FROM @newValues) p  
    UNPIVOT ( [To] FOR [Field] 
                IN ( CommitteeID , CommitteeName , CommitteeMemberID)) as UNPVT
)
SELECT F.*, T.[To] FROM FromTable F FULL JOIN ToTable T ON F.[Field] = T.[Field]
```

New columns can be easily added to SELECT and IN part of the query.

*For easily determine missing column I used FULL JOIN*